# No Internet after reinstalling on Dell Mini 9

Tags: wireless, 10.04, dell-mini-9

I had to reinstall 10.04.  It had been working with no problems and then I did something.  I decided that reinstalling the OS would be the easiest fix.

After reinstalling I cannot access the internet.  I am using a Dell Mini 9.

Might I need new drivers?

Answer (score 2):

This problem may occur in wireless internet connection. First connect with wired Internet connection.

In terminal

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

And then , you can try with wireless.

You also need to check

System>Administration>Hardware Drivers

Answer (score 1):

It most certainly is your wireless which you may need to reinstall..First a little advice.Remove what was working before as it is out of date and reinstall the drivers for your ( I assume you have broadcom wifi - most dells mini 9s do ) broadcom.

It is quite simple and here is how to do it in 4 very easy steps in your terminal.

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

this removes your old driver

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

This will reinstall it using the best set up for your version of Ubuntu

Then the last steps areto switch it on so you do not have to reboot!

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 ssb wl

sudo modprobe wl
```

It will build the driver for you in  front of your eyes.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You probably need the firmware installed for the wireless card.  Start with the `b43-fwcutter` package.